# How to integrate custom scripts into locust helm chart stable/locust?

Tags: kubernetes, locust, kubernetes-helm

I have a repo for maintaining multiple locust scripts to load test many of my target-hosts/services.

How to integrate these scripts into the helm installation of stable/locust on one of k8s cluster?

We currently run locust master and slave manually on different ec2 instances and perform load tests on that.

We want to setup locust on k8s. This is in preliminary stages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an outstanding issue with that chart at the moment that it doesn't provide a clear way to inject scripts. You currently have to effectively add them yourself to the docker image or create your own copy of the chart. This could be made more flexible and there is aspiration to do so - see https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/2560

Comment: Probably the easiest way for now would be to create your own copy of https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/locust and put the files in '/tasks' and then you can install your chart straight from source code by doing helm install with the directory name as the parameter instead of stable/locust